# Access Cookie into sub domains

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to host multiple sites under one domain. But currently I am working on localhost, so I added these 2 lines to my etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 something.com
127.0.0.1 orders.something.com
```

There are 2 applications hosted in IIS. One can be browsed using: `orders.something.com/OrdersSSO` and other can be browsed using `something.com/SSOSample/`.

I created authentication cookie using this code in `something.com/SSOSample/`:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                                                                "abc",
                                                                DateTime.Now,
                                                                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // value of time out property
                                                                true, // Value of IsPersistent property
                                                                String.Empty,
                                                                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

                            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                            HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(
                        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                        encryptedTicket);

                            Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

So I am logged in this application. However when I browse orders.something.com/OrdersSSO I don't get my authentication cookie.

This is my forms section in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" timeout="2880" domain=".something.com" />
    </authentication>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your cookie doamin has not been correctly set.

Try something like this :

```
authCookie.Domain = ".something.com"
```

Note the "." in front of the domain name, that's what makes it work for any subdomain of something.com.

Comment: You still need authCookie.Domain = ".something.com" because you're setting the cookie manually. Your web.config domain attribute will be used when ASP.NET automatically extends the cookie expiration.